# Specflow : Parameters in code file not storing latest values from feature file in specflow

Tags: c#, bdd, specflow

Below is the step from feature file :

```
Given I logged into application with username "UserName" and password "Password"
```

Below is the binded code for the above step in code file :

```
[Given(@"I logged into application with username ""(.*)"" and password ""(.*)""")]
public void GivenILoggedIntoApplicationWithUsernameAndPassword(string _userName, string _password)
{
    driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();            
    string url = "http://" + _userName + ":" + _password + "@" + ***.com/;            
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
}
```

The parameter _userName not taking latest value as username as per the steps but taking old values.

Comment: Your code in the step file doesn't look correct to me.  Try formatting it like this to escape out the quotes: [Given(@"I logged into application with username \""(.*)\"" and password \""(.*)\""")]  Not sure if that is your issue or not, but try that.

Comment: Do you have `Scenario outline` and `Examples`? Can you show more of your `.feature` file, maybe there is something else of relevance for your case. Please edit your question if you do.

Comment: Also, what i noticed here are 2 things. First, what you have here `""(.)""` takes only one character. I guess you want to add asterisk (*) after dot - `""(.*)""`, so your regex accepts one or more characters.
Second, in your question `[Given(@"I logged into application with username ""(.)"" and password ""(.)""")]` has `and password`part which is written with italic, which leads me to think that something is messed up with step bindings.

Comment: Which version of SpecFlow are you using? Are you sure the code-behind file (feature.cs) is being regenerated properly?

Comment: Yes, there are issues with regenerating new changes when .feature file is modified (or new one is added). Depending on your generator tool (MSBuild, SpecFlowSingleFileGenerator), you might have same problem. If you want to confirm that, try to add new .feature file and see if code behind (.feature.cs file) comes with it. If there is no .feature.cs file, then you have problem with (re)generating code behind, as @GregBurghardt mentioned.

Comment: The step from feature file is correct as well as the code binded with it. Actually i am facing very critical issue like 1. When i add a scenario in feature file it is not reflecting in test explorer after build. 2. When i delete a step from scenario it is still executing that deleted step. 3. When i update a step in feature file with with new values then the code behind is taking the old values. 4. When i add a step in feature file the step is getting skipped at run time.